# Lagrange Multipliers vs Plugin method

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

With an equality constraint it is possible to express one of the variables of the constraint into the objective function and simplify the problem.
However, I have found a few examples where this plugin method does not show all the critical point the standard Lagrangian would.

Does anybody know why this happens from a **general** point of view?

The example I started with is 
$x^2 - y^2$ s.t $x^2+y^2=1$

Comment: Why don't you show us such an example? There might be several reasons.

Comment: In your example, we clearly have $-1\leq x, y\leq 1$, but that's information you lose once you've used the constraint to write $y^2 = 1-x^2$ and rewritten the function you want to optimise into $2x^2 - 1$, unless you keep the constraint in some form, such as specifying that $|x|\leq 1$. You won't find the maximal points at $(\pm 1, 0)$ just from differentiating, although the minimal points $(0, \pm 1)$ are there.

Comment: Exact @Arthur but I wonder whether there is a general approach to avoid using the plugin method when it might not be so obvious.